# ctrl + c will not kill terminal (osx bash) program `screen`

Tags: gnu-screen

I got into a GNU `screen` and couldn't get out of it, it was hogging my terminal window. I tried a number of hotkey combos with no success. I've listed a few of the hotkey combos below.

**Command**

```
$ screen /dev/tty.usbmodem641 9600
```

**Hotkey attempts**

- ctrl + c
- ctrl + C
- ctrl + z
- ctrl + Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While writing the question I thought of new places to find the answer. Here's what I found:

## Press `ctrl + a` then separately press `k`

Note that this kills the window and is not recommended by the reference guide below. This is the best way I've found to kill my `screen` from OSX.

*http://aperiodic.net/screen/quick_reference*

Comment: You can also find that in `man screen`. Note that meta DETACH does not kill screen, so it does not answer your question. It only detaches it. A single Control-D or exit to close the shell would have closed it. (assuming no .screenrc set to spawn multiple shells).

Comment: @Hennes you are correct. I quickly found that I could not connect again because the resource was busy. I tried ctrl+D with no success on `OSX`. I have modified my answer to reflect what kills the current screen and frees the resource. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: I have no OSX experience, but I use screen on FreeBSD, which is similar. Usually closing all programs (by default a shell) will help. If that fails either use the combination to kill screen or use `ps` and `kill`. Prefeably starting with SIGHUP to cleanly close programs. If that fails try -15 and -9.